# NEO4J create statement long strings from csv

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Please i dont understand why this statement is ok one by one, but failled if i paste alls item and run

---

```
"CREATE (n:shakspeare {name:""KING HENRY IV - 1"" , description:""KING HENRY IV ...""})"

"CREATE (n:shakspeare {name:""WESTMORELAND -1"" , description:""My liege, this haste was hot in question,...""})"

"CREATE (n:shakspeare {name:""KING HENRY IV - 2"" , description:""It seems ....""})"
"CREATE (n:shakspeare {name:""WESTMORELAND -2"" , description:""This match'd with....""})"
```

---

Thanks for help

Bruno

Comment: Could you provide the error message you are getting?

Comment: How do you exec those? I see at least the csv double quotes and the apostrophe as potential issues

Comment: error: type help to more info....        what is the right syntax for this type of long test statement ?  Thanks for help

Comment: But you're not executing them with all the csv double quotes around them?

Comment: thanks for answer, yes agree with you, but the double quotes are'nt in the statement.  the statement is generated with an excel formulas: ="CREATE ("&C3&":ccmctrl  {name:"""&B3&""" , description:"""&D3&"""})"       and it's ok if excute it one by one, but failled if i copy several lines.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You are re-declaring the 'n' variable in every CREATE statement. You need to declare different names in each CREATE.

Comment: hello, i have modified as you request, but still failled.

Answer (score 1):

These should work:

```
CREATE (henry:Play {name:"KING HENRY IV - 1" , description:"KING HENRY IV ..."})
CREATE (westmoreland:Play {name:"WESTMORELAND -1" , description:"My liege, this haste was hot in question,..."})

CREATE (henry2:Play {name:"KING HENRY IV - 2" , description:"It seems ...."})
CREATE (westmoreland2:Pay {name:"WESTMORELAND -2" , description:"This match'd with...."})
```

I would probably not label them `:Shakespeare`, but with `:Play` and connect them to a `:Author` node with the `name:"Shakespeare"`

Check out the free graph databases book for a the chapter on the plays of William Shakespeare.